# SQL query distict count using inner join

Tags: sql-server

Need help ensuring the below query doesn't return inaccurate results.

```
select @billed = count(a.[counter]) from [dbo].cxitems a with (nolock)  
        inner join [dbo].cxitemhist b with (nolock) on a.[counter] = b.cxlink 
    where b.[eventtype] in ('BILLED','REBILLED')
        and b.[datetime] between @begdate and @enddate
```

The query is "mostly" accurate as is, however there is a slight possibility that cxitemhist table could contain more than 1 "billed" record for given date range.  I only need to count item as "Billed" once during given date range.

Comment: With no details other than a query we can't possibly tell you if it is "optimized". I also notice you have NOLOCK. Are you aware of all the caveats of that hint? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows? Meaning your query results will be correct most of the time but every now and then the count is going to be wrong.

Comment: And why is this tagged with mysql when the syntax looks clearly like sql server?

Comment: removed MySql tag - you can sleep well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join on a sub query the limits you to one row for each combination of fields used for the join:

```
select @billed = count(a.[counter]) 
from [dbo].cxitems a 
inner join (
    select distinct cxlink 
    from [dbo].cxitemhist
    where [eventtype] in ('BILLED','REBILLED')
       and [datetime] between @begdate and @enddate
) b on a.[counter] = b.cxlink
```

You can also use the [APPLY operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of a join here, but you'll have to check against your data to see which gives better performance.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.  I did however re-add the NOLOCK hints. As much as this seems to annoy Mr. Lange (above), I am using this query for a dashboard application only and can afford the occasional innaccuracy - I anticipate the results will be refreshed often and cannot afford the possibility of affecting primary processes.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to count records from the `cxitems` table, that have any corresponding records from the `cxitemhist` table, you can use the `exists` clause with a subquery.

```
select @billed = count(a.[counter]) from [dbo].cxitems a 
   where exists(select * from [dbo].cxitemhist b 
       where a.[counter] = b.cxlink 
         and b.[eventtype] in ('BILLED','REBILLED')
         and b.[datetime] between @begdate and @enddate)
```

Cannot really say how this will affect performance, without specific data, though, but it should be comparably fast with your code.